# Can class methods be declared as a reference in ES 6 or 7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to grasp [this piece of code](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/helpers/connectData.js) from `react-redux-universal-hot-example` (my god, look how far we got!).

Anyways..

They are declaring 2 static methods for a class as a reference to 2 function parameters.

```
export default function connectData(fetchData, fetchDataDeferred) {
  return function wrapWithFetchData(WrappedComponent) {
    class ConnectData extends Component {

      static fetchData = fetchData;
      static fetchDataDeferred = fetchDataDeferred;

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
    }

    return ConnectData;
  };
}
```

The point is.. This works... But is it supported by either ES6 or ES7? Can you implement a class member as a reference to something you receive as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, ES6 and ES7 does not change how functions work so they are still objects and objects are references.

Comment: Properties can contain arbitrary values. That didn't change.

Comment: Where is ES6 OR 7 actually implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not valid ES6 according to [the grammar for a `ClassElement`](https://gist.github.com/rbuckton/0d8c1f1c607f52f5ae37#ClassElement), and fails when [attempted on an ES6 REPL](https://jsoverson.github.io/es6repl/#__v2:let%20method%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0Aclass%20Example%20%7B%20static%20_method%20%3D%20method%3B%20%7D):

```
const method = () => {};
class Example { static _method = method; }
//=> Unexpected token (2:31)
```

...but is [proposed for ES7+](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties), which presumably is the functionality the babel plugin implements.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Essentially they return this:

```
return {
  fetchData         : fetchData,
  fetchDataDeferred : fetchDataDeferred,
  render            : function()  {...},
  __proto__         : Component 
};
```

Not exactly but conceptually it is close enough ...